# Specific Border Radius CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to create a div that has rounded corners on the top left and top right, but not not the bottom two corners. Is there a value of `-webkit-border-radius` that lets you have a curved edge only on certain corners of a div?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
border-radius: topleft topright bottomright bottomleft;
```

So:

```css
div {
  background: red;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is border-radius for each corner:

```
border-top-left-radius
border-bottom-right-radius
border-top-right-radius
border-bottom-left-radius
```

I think mozilla needs the prefix like `-moz-border-radius-topright`

Comment: The last few versions of firefox haven't required the prefix. Not a terrible idea to include it anyway, but it isn't needed for the more recent versions.

Comment: @apaul34208 100% agree.

Answer (score 3):

You can set these properties:

```
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
```

In order to work with Firefox:

```
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
-moz-border-radius-topright:10px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft:10px;
```